# Is there a way to describe type of the object field with its key name and value type?

Tags: typescript

**The following code shows the problem:**

```js
interface IHuman {
    name: string,
    carModel: "Toyota" | "Mazda" | "Nissan",
    age: number
}

type TInnerField = {filterField: keyof IHuman, valueThisField: IHuman[keyof IHuman]} // => it's wrong described type, how properly to do it?

const human: IHuman = {
    name: "Josh",
    carModel: "Toyota",
    age: 25
}
const innerFieldError: TInnerField = {filterField: "name", valueThisField: 15} // => Should be the error, because field "name" has to be a string type
const innerFieldSuccess: TInnerField = {filterField: "name", valueThisField: "My new name"} // => OK


function changeHuman (humanInnerField: TInnerField, human: IHuman): IHuman {
    return {
        ...human,
        [humanInnerField.filterField]: humanInnerField.valueThisField
    }
}
```

**What I tried**
I found the way to solve this problem, but i reckon that this one is very manual decision.

```js
export type THumanName = {filterType: "name", value: IHuman["name"]};
export type THumanCarModel = {filterType: "carModel", value: IHuman["carModel"]};
export type THumanAge = {filterType: "age", value: IHuman["age"]};
```

and then create almost similar function

```js
function changeHuman (humanInnerField: THumanName | THumanCarModel | THumanAge, human: IHuman): IHuman {
    return {
        ...human,
        [humanInnerField.filterField]: humanInnerField.valueThisField
    }
}
```

Is it possible to solve this problem automatically?
Thanks for your answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works: [ts playground example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIAkCuBbOJkDeAUMqSHNhAFzIDOYUoA5gDQmkJxQCyA9gCYQANjQBEAFV4BPXmDijkAH2SjucAF795SlQDlgtWnlFtSyOE2rIQOAEbQiAXwDcRImCkAHFONQgQ0ABiwML8ADziyBAAHpAg-LTIANYQMjBoWLggAHzIALyEMMBCkFDBoTTiLMgAbnBCmBDiABYG5UL8NBg4eADa4gC6Lm4IvCD0yKABZSEdAKJQULxQlX7T7eGi5JSiuQUERSVBs50q2xAmtfWNLW0nNACMAKwuyAD0b8gLS1BEo+NgSb+Y6hADKmAQSEMq2BM1CYS2FAue0KxVKGzE50udQaTVatAxKm4UmsEAA7tYkaJhkQYJgQAgwMAxshIPQIlFYhB4okUmkMj0cgAKaIw9YnCLZACUhBpbLAQoOaJBHUxVOqOJu+MJz0cUuc70+32W7gg9EVh3R9zO6quuNuBOtome1P1huQAHkkqbzUqjnDVSoLBcNdc8XcKioXXqDR8vosTfKLcqA6dRMHsWGHTqXm64x6ANJEIA)

```js
type TInnerField<T extends keyof IHuman> = {filterField: T, valueThisField: IHuman[T]};
```

The downside is that you have to add the key name to variable declarations but for function arguments the key name is automatically detected.